# FormUrlEncoded deprecated in RetroFit?

Tags: retrofit

I found that in 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT version the `FormUrlEncoded` annotation is no longer supported:

```
} else if (annotationType == FormUrlEncoded.class) {
        if (requestType != RequestType.SIMPLE) {
          throw methodError("Only one encoding annotation is allowed.");
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Form URL encoding shall return!");
        //requestType = RequestType.FORM_URL_ENCODED;
      }
```

Still, when I remove the annotation I got another exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoginService.login: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding. (parameter #1)
```

Why is so and why the `FormUrlEncoded` annotation itself has not been annotated with `@Deparcated` annotation?

Comment: Because it's not deprecated. It currently doesn't work, hence the fact that it always throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is there an alternative in snapshot version to send form parameters in POST request? Or I should use, fork, and contribute only to stable (i.e., release) versions?